# Unsupported Media Type error while trying to upload image from Android client

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I am learning Java REST web services and I am trying to upload an image file with Android. Below is the client and server code. I am getting Http Status code 415: The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method . What could be wrong? Thank you.

The Android client code looks like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        FileBody fileContent = new FileBody(new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                        + "Pictures/" + IMAGE_FILE_NAME));

        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        multipartEntity.addPart("file", fileContent);

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {       
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
```

and the server code looks like this:

```
    @POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "C://uploadedFiles/"
            + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    saveToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded via Jersey based RESTFul Webservice to: "
            + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}
```

Comment: Here is the message error from Glassfish server: A message body reader for Java class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, and MIME media type multipart/form-data; boundary=K4c4I6YBly_Pxue6y7LYEkExohW90gmZIGI0 was not found. The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are: */* -> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvidercom.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider and more...

Comment: have you tried to: 
 `httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", new StringBody("image/jpg"));`

Comment: Still getting error message: Http Status code 415: The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve the issue. Below is the code that works. Thank you.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator
                + "Pictures/" + IMAGE_FILE_NAME);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();

        ByteArrayBody fileBody = new ByteArrayBody(byte_arr,
                "imageFileName.jpg");

        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        multipartEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = null;
            try {

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


               } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }
```